# Button text doesn't show on first load

Tags: ios, swift

I have changed button text on swift like this:

```
btn_text.setTitle("Hello", for: .normal)
```

inside `viewDidLoad`

which works well except on the very first load of the app it just shows "button".

So when I install the app for the first time on a device it just shows default button name as opposed to what I assigned to it. But if I kill the app and run it again it works just fine afterward. Is there something I am supposed to be doing for the first load? Might be on app delagate? Or am I supposed to be putting it somewhere else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your override of viewDidLoad() runs

```
super.viewDidLoad()
```

before you modify the button title.

Comment: Super.viewdidload() is already being called. Still not sure why on the very first load nothing loads up.  Thanks for the help